# Filter Grid.Mvc on client side without postback

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, grid.mvc

I am new to Grid.MVC and I am using it to display a list of Results. However, when I filter or sort the columns, it posts back to the action to get the results. Is there a way that I can filter the results on client side using Grid.MVC?

Comment: https://gridmvcajax.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0):

You can use Ajax Grid.Mvc control from NuGet instead. It will still postback to server to fetch the data but via ajax call. This will provide better experience for the end users.

This is built on Grid.Mvc.Redux.

[Link to Nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Grid.Mvc.Ajax/)

[Check the demo here](https://github.com/TheNinjaBrotherhood/Grid-Mvc-Ajax-Demo)